# Google maps Marker not working properly; React, TS, google maps api project

Tags: google-maps, compilation, localhost, google-maps-markers, react-typescript

The code works fine when it is deployed on netlify, but when I run it locally with 'npm run start' for development it is having issue. the map displays fine but the issue is with rendering the marker consistently.

issue- when I add the line

```
                        <Marker position={userLocation}></Marker>
```

for the first time after a reload(or recompilation) the marker shows up, but if I reload(or recompile) without changing this particular line or anything related to the map the marker will not render, the map shows up fine, everything else is working fine but just the marker will not be displayed on the map.

here are the imports used for google maps:

```
import {
    GoogleMap,
    Marker,
} from '@react-google-maps/api';
```

here is the code for rendering the map and the marker:

```
const mapOptions = useMemo<MapOptions>(() => {
        return { disableDefaultUI: true, clickableIcons: false, mapId: 'a4e414a0f3xxxx6' }; //
    }, []);
```

```
 const onLoad = useCallback((map: any) => (mapRef.current = map), []);

 return (
        <>
            <form>
                <label>Your location: </label>
                <span>
                    <Places
                        setcity={getCity}
                        setLocation={(position: LatLngLiteral): void => {
                            setUserLocation(position);
                            mapRef.current?.panTo(position);
                        }}
                    ></Places>

                    <span className="description"> City: </span>
                    <select className="dropdown" name="cities">
                        <option value="around you">Around you</option>
                        {citiesBC.length &&
                            citiesBC.map((city, i) => (
                                <option key={i} value={city}>
                                    {city}
                                </option>
                            ))}
                    </select>
                    <span className="description"> Show all stores: </span>
                    <input type="checkbox" className="checkboxx" onClick={toggleDisplayAllStore} />
                </span>
            </form>
            <br />
            <MapContainer>
                <div className="container">
                    <GoogleMap
                        zoom={10}
                        center={userLocation}
                        mapContainerClassName="map-actual"
                        options={mapOptions}
                        onLoad={onLoad}
                    >
                        <Marker position={userLocation}></Marker> // line in question
                    </GoogleMap>
                </div>
            </MapContainer>
        </>
    );
```

I have tried reinstalling all the modules and using different browsers nothing seems to work.